# Got Index out of Bound while trying to get status of VM compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resrc, vm, expand="instanceView")

Tags: python, azure, fastapi, azure-sdk-python, python-development-mode

I am getting below error when trying to get the status of the VM inside while loop:

```
 File "C:\Users\RohitMishra\Documents\cost-controller-engine\services\service.py", line 533, in schedule
    compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resrc, vm, expand="instanceView")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Below is my code:

```
  Status_vm = (
    compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resrc, vm, expand="instanceView").instance_view.statuses[1].display_status)
    print("STATUS  VMMMM---",Status_vm)
    if Status_vm =="VM deallocated":
        compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_start(resrc, vm)
        while True:
            logger.info("enterd into while loop for starting VM..")
            print("STATATAus >>>>>: ",Status_vm)
            Status_vm = (
                compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resrc, vm, expand="instanceView")
                .instance_view.statuses[1]
                .display_status
            )
            logger.info(f"Status.. @: {Status_vm}")
            if Status_vm =="VM running":
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(constants.SLEEP_TIME)
        return "Successfully running your VM"
```

Could you guys help me with any code or logic in python to resolve this issue...

Comment: That feels deserving of an issue declaration at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues (I work at MS in this team)

Answer (score 0):

Like Laurent Mazuel said it would be great to have an issue with a full stack trace in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues. I'm also wondering if it could be `.instance_view.statuses[1]` that you're calling on the returned object from `compute_client.virtual_machines.get`, are you sure there are at least 2 statuses on the instance view?